# Divide a list of points into clusters based on the gap between them

Tags: cluster-analysis

I would like to know how I can divide the attached list of points to as many clusters as possible based on the gap between the patches. Then I can decide which one should be kept and which remove. I tried different options in Findclusters command but none of them gave me a correct answer. Any help is really appreciated.

https://pastebin.com/WMC4GhxE

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This gets you four clusters with points grouped together in `ccmp`. The two large islands are depicted in orange and blue, the small long island in green, and a tiny island in red.

```
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[data, 8];
ccmp = ConnectedComponents[nng];
ListPointPlot3D[ccmp]

(* Length@ccmp == 4 *)
```

[image: connected components list plot]

Comment: Thank you! It worked! However, when I changed the value of the coefficient in the bracket of the NeasrestNeighborGraph from 8 to 4, the number of patches changed to 5 and showed me another small island as a separate cluster which is correct basically. Is there any criterion to select the value of the coefficient? For example, the value of 1 gave me 30 patches. I am asking as I need to apply the script on different data and need to use a constant coefficient.

Comment: I just chose 8 randomly. If instead you put a list `{k,r}` it uses the `k` nearest within distance `r`, and `{All,r}` connects all elements within distance `r`

Comment: Thank you for the response! By distance, you mean Euclideandistance?

Comment: Yes by default, but it also takes an option `DistanceFunction`, e.g , `DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance`

Comment: Another question and appreciate your response. Is always the output from the largest list (with the most number of members) to the smallest one?

Comment: Do you mean does it sort them by number of points in each cluster? Yes I think it sorts them, try `nng = NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1024], 4];
Length /@ ConnectedComponents[nng]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109306/discussion-between-mehdi-ebadi-and-flinty).

Comment: You can readily label the regions: `Show[ListPointPlot3D[ccmp],
 ListPointPlot3D[Callout[#[[2]], Style["\[ScriptCapitalR]" <> ToString[#[[1]]], 14, Bold]] & /@Transpose[{Range@Length@ccmp, Mean /@ ccmp}], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]]]`